# Tracking Source/Medium with Enhanced Ecommerce event

Tags: google-analytics

I have implemented the GA Enhanced Ecommerce in my website, on some event I send this request to GA through JavaScript, like this:

```
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'name': 'Donation',
    'category': cookieData.category,
    'price': cookieData.revenue,
    'quantity': 1
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': cookieData.transactionId,
    'affiliation': cookieData.affiliation,
    'revenue': cookieData.revenue
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This part is working without issues, all the data I need is logged where it belongs. Hovewer, on Acquisition > All Traffic > Source/Medium, all Revenue is logged in the `(direct) / (none)` row, even though most of the traffic comes through the `google / cpc` source/medium. Consequently, in Acquisition > Google Ads > Campaigns, all Revenues are also at $0.00, even though I can track that much traffic from my Ad Campaigns land on the 'Thank You' page which is seen after the Donation.

When I inspected the data that is sent on this event, I can see that a bunch of other data that is usually sent on the page load is also sent: few different IDs, referrer, etc... So I have no idea if I am doing something wrong, and why the source of traffic that increases the revenue isn't logged properly.

Is there any additional data I have to send together with this set of data? And where to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a rather peculiar question, and I can't offer any technical explanation, but I managed to work out a solution to my problem.

Instead of using the `ga()` global object/function, I switched to `gtag()`, as I found out that by using the `ga()`, it was like I was creating a blank Google Analytics object with no context. Google Tag object was already filled with all the contextual info I needed, so just by adding a new event with the Enhanced Ecommerce info, it did what I wanted. This is the code I ended up using:

```js
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    "transaction_id": cookieData.transactionId,
    "affiliation": cookieData.affiliation,
    "value": cookieData.revenue,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Donation",
            "category": cookieData.category,
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": cookieData.revenue,
        }
    ]
});
```

And now it behaves the same regarding the Enhanced Ecommerce info, but is also tracking the source/medium and campaign of all the revenue gathered.